# Formatting Time, Amount In Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, web-scraping

My data is returned in this way. I need to return all the values in a list ensuring the time format and fare amount corrected as I explained. I want to remove the comma in fare, and AM & PM in departure and arrival. Many thanks in advance. As there are about 3 flightCodes and all together 18 fares.

**The returned response.**

```
[ { flightCode: 'SHA735',
    departure: '01:30 PM',
    arrival: '01:55 PM',
    fareCode: 'T Class',
    fare: '4,000',
    baggage: '20' },
  { flightCode: 'SHA735',
    departure: '01:30 PM',
    arrival: '01:55 PM',
    fareCode: 'B Class',
    fare: '5,900',
    baggage: '20' },
  { flightCode: 'SHA735',
    departure: '01:30 PM',
    arrival: '01:55 PM',
    fareCode: 'I Class',
    fare: '6,600',
    baggage: '20' },
  { flightCode: 'SHA735',
    departure: '01:30 PM',
    arrival: '01:55 PM',
    fareCode: 'H Class',
    fare: '7,500',
    baggage: '20' },
  { flightCode: 'SHA735',
    departure: '01:30 PM',
    arrival: '01:55 PM',
    fareCode: 'H Class',
    fare: '7,500',
    baggage: '20' } ]
```

**Expected Result:**

```
[ { flightCode: 'SHA735',
    departure: '01:30',
    arrival: '01:55',
    fareCode: 'T Class',
    fare: '4000',
    baggage: '20' },
  { flightCode: 'SHA735',
    departure: '01:30',
    arrival: '01:55',
    fareCode: 'S Class',
    fare: '5000',
    baggage: '20' },
  { flightCode: 'SHA735',
    departure: '01:30',
    arrival: '01:55',
    fareCode: 'E Class',
    fare: '5300',
    baggage: '20' },
  { flightCode: 'SHA735',
    departure: '01:30',
    arrival: '01:55',
    fareCode: 'B Class',
    fare: '5900',
    baggage: '20' }
]
```

**My Javascript code is below.**

```
 const $ = cheerio.load(html);
        const format = {
             klasses: new Array(), 
        }
        const result = [];

        const flights = $('.flight-result > .tbody').find('.no-of-flights').toArray();

        flights.forEach(function(flight, _id) {

            result[_id] = Object.assign({},format);
            const flightCode = $(flight).find('p.font-reg.redcolor').contents().filter(function(){
                return this.type === 'text';
            }).text().trim();
            const times = $(flight).find('p.font-reg.redcolor').find('small').html().match(/\d\d:\d\d [AP]M/g);
            const flightClassContainer = $(flight).find('.flightclasscontainer').toArray();

            flightClassContainer.forEach((flightClass, __id) => {
                result[_id].klasses[__id]   = {

                    flightCode:$(flight).find('p.font-reg.redcolor').contents().filter(function () {
                        return this.type === 'text';
                    }).text().trim(),
                    departure: times[0],
                    arrival: times[1],
                    fareCode: $(flightClass).find('.class').text(),
                    fare: $(flightClass).find('.price').text(),
                    baggage: '20'
                 }
            })
        });

        let items = [].concat(...result.map(o => o.klasses));
         console.log(items);
        return items;
```

Comment: Jai Nepal, see the answer and let me know if that is what you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `split(' ')[0]` to remove the time parameter `AM/PM` and `replace(',','')` to replace the comma in fare.

```js
var flights = [ { flightCode: 'SHA735',
    departure: '01:30 PM',
    arrival: '01:55 PM',
    fareCode: 'T Class',
    fare: '4,000',
    baggage: '20' },
  { flightCode: 'SHA735',
    departure: '01:30 PM',
    arrival: '01:55 PM',
    fareCode: 'B Class',
    fare: '5,900',
    baggage: '20' },
  { flightCode: 'SHA735',
    departure: '01:30 PM',
    arrival: '01:55 PM',
    fareCode: 'I Class',
    fare: '6,600',
    baggage: '20' },
  { flightCode: 'SHA735',
    departure: '01:30 PM',
    arrival: '01:55 PM',
    fareCode: 'H Class',
    fare: '7,500',
    baggage: '20' },
  { flightCode: 'SHA735',
    departure: '01:30 PM',
    arrival: '01:55 PM',
    fareCode: 'H Class',
    fare: '7,500',
    baggage: '20' } ];

flights.map((flight) => {
  flight.departure = flight.departure.split(' ')[0];
  flight.arrival = flight.arrival.split(' ')[0];
  flight.fare = flight.fare.replace(',','');
});
console.log(flights);
```

Comment: flight.fare.replace is not a function.

Comment: @AshokBhattarai Did you check the snippet. It is not giving that error.

Comment: Sorry error in my code. I have changed the comma earlier. Thanks Its working.

Comment: @AshokBhattarai you can accept the answer if it was helpful to you

Comment: As all the data is returned using this code, the returned data is not completely pushed into my db table. How can I acheive this. Previously for another airline this is done like this.     items.push({
      `flightCode,
      departure,
      arrival,
      fare,
      fareCode,
      baggage,
    });
  });

  return items;` and all the data was pushed into db table.